# use javascript to display django object

Tags: javascript, python, django

I want to implement below using javascript so row click it will get index and display object of this index.

in django template this is working.

```
<div>{{ project.0.customer_name}}</div>
<div>{{ project.1.customer_name}}</div>
```

but the below javascript are not working even I get the correct ID.

```
var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
var id=  parseInt(cell.innerHTML);
// not working
document.getElementById('lblname').innerHTML =   '{{ project.id.customer_name}}';

// this is also working but what I want is dynamic base on row click
document.getElementById('lblname').innerHTML = '{{ project.1.customer_name}}';
```

display django object using index in javascript.

Comment: **Warning** Your code is vulnarable to XSS, or cross site scripting. If your customer name contains quotes a attacker can execute arbitrary java-script. See https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/02/18/safely-including-data-for-javascript-in-a-django-template/ for some info on properly preventing XSS in django.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand what is happening with your code:

Templates like this are processed on the server:

```
'{{ project.id.customer_name}}'
```

I believe you do not have `project.id` on your server side, so you get `None` in the above line, and the moustache tag becomes smth like an empty string, and actual JavaScript code is like this:

```
document.getElementById('lblname').innerHTML = '';
```

It is only now that JS code is executed, and you can imagine what it will do.

What you want is processing moustache tags after the `id` variable has been set in JS, which is **not how stuff works** (at least, if you don't have some crazy tool chain).

**One way** of achieving what you want is to provide the whole `project` object (or array) to JavaScript by doing the following:

```
<script>
const project = {{ project|safe }};
</script>
```

A complete Django template could look like this (I used `<span>`s instead of table cells:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>django test</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
{% for item in project %}
<span data-id="{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ forloop.counter }}</span>
{% endfor %}

<div id="output" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse;">
</div>

<script>
const project = {{ project|safe }};
const spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
const output = document.getElementById('output');

const onSpanClick = (event) => {
    const id = parseInt(event.target.getAttribute('data-id'), 10) - 1; // forloop.counter is 1-based, JS arrays are 0-based
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = project[id].customer_name;
    output.appendChild(div);
}

Array.from(spans).forEach(span => {
    span.addEventListener('click', onSpanClick);
})

</script>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**Another way** is the AJAX way: you create an API endpoint on your server side, so that an URL like example.com/api/customer_name/?id=999 responds to you with the name of customer id=999 when you click on some element and trigger an XMLHttpRequest with param id=999.

Comment: nice explanation on project.id, now I'm enlighten and the script give I will try and it's look it will work, what I'll just need to do is put the object on javascript and from javascript object variable that's where I should do the indexing thank you